# Parse a date in various formats

Tags: parsing, datetime, haskell

I have a problem similar to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174372/haskell-date-parsing-and-formatting), namely reading in text which describes a date - in various formats. I want to use the `parseTimeM` function from `Date.Time` module in `time` package.

My current solution can probably be improved style wise but it should remain easy to read and easy to extend. Suggestion?

```
readDate3 :: Text ->   UTCTime
readDate3 datestring  =

    case shortMonth of
        Just t -> t
        Nothing -> case longMonth of
            Just t2 -> t2
            Nothing -> case monthPoint of
                Just t3 -> t3
                Nothing -> case germanNumeralShort of
                  Just t3 -> t3
                  Nothing -> case germanNumeral of
                    Just t3 -> t3
                    Nothing -> case isoformat of
                      Just t4 -> t4
                      Nothing -> errorT   ["readDate3", datestring, "is not parsed"]

    where
        shortMonth = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%b %-d, %Y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
        longMonth = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%B %-d, %Y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
        monthPoint = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%b. %-d, %Y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
        germanNumeral = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%-d.%-m.%Y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
        germanNumeralShort = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%-d.%-m.%y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
        isoformat = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
            "%Y-%m-%d" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
```

Comment: I think you can use the `>>=` combinator instead of this huge `case` expression.

Comment: I tried but did not succeed (I nearly never use the `>>=` constructors. Can you show me the start of the chain?

Comment: @ForceBru That's not applicable in this case - `>>=` continues the computation on `Just`, whereas here we need to continue it on `Nothing`.

Comment: @user855443 Small detail: `>>=` is a function, not a constructor. I know that's nitpicking a bit, but these details can start to matter in more advanced stuff (e.g. you can pattern-match on constructors but not on functions).

Answer (score 4):

## Don't repeat yourself

Your code violates the DRY principle. If we replace

```
germanNumeralShort = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
    "%-d.%-m.%y" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
isoformat = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale
    "%Y-%m-%d" (t2s datestring) :: Maybe UTCTime
...
```

with

```
parse format = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale format (t2s datestring)

germanNumeralShort = parse "%-d.%-m.%y"
isoformat          = parse "%Y-%m-%d"
...
```

then we immediately notice that we use `parse` on all formats after another till we find a suitable one.

This can be modelled with `map parse`, e.g.

```
map parse
    [ "%b %-d, %Y"
    , "%B %-d, %Y"
    , "%b. %-d, %Y"
    , "%-d.%-m.%Y"
    , "%-d.%-m.%y"
    , "%Y-%m-%d"
    ]
```

We could use `<|>` alternatively, e.g.

```
parse "%b %-d, %Y" <|> parse "%B %-d, %Y" <|> ...
```

but that's less flexible than the list approach.

## Use [`asum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) to get a single `Maybe` from a list of `Maybe`s

To get a single `Maybe a` from `[Maybe a]`, we can use `asum`. To get the `errorT`, we just need to pattern match on a single result and end up with

```
readDate3 :: Text ->   UTCTime
readDate3 datestring = case result of
   Nohing -> errorT ["readDate3", datestring, "is not parsed"]
   Just t -> t
 where 
   parse format = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale format (t2s datestring) 
   result = asum . map parse $
        [ "%b %-d, %Y"
        , "%B %-d, %Y"
        , "%b. %-d, %Y"
        , "%-d.%-m.%Y"
        , "%-d.%-m.%y"
        , "%Y-%m-%d"
        ]
```

As the current strings are missing some documentation, we could introduce additional types to remedy that:

```
data DateFormat = ShortMonth
                | LongMonth
                | MonthPoint
                | GermanNumeral
                | GermanNumeralShort
                | ISOFormat

toFormatString :: DateFormat -> String
toFormatString f = case f of
    ShortMonth -> "%b %-d, %Y"
    LongMonth  -> "%B %-d, %Y"
    MonthPoint -> "%b. %-d, %Y"
    -- other left as an exercise
```

We can also use `fromMaybe` to get rid of the last pattern match and end up with

```
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

readDate :: Text ->   UTCTime
readDate datestring = 
    fromMaybe (errorT ["readDate", datestring, "is not parsed"]) $
      asum . map parse $
        [ ShortMonth
        , LongMonth
        , MonthPoint
        , GermanNumeral
        , GermanNumeralShort
        , ISOFormat
        ]
 where 
   parse format = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale (toFormatString format) (t2s datestring)
```

Comment: The final pattern match can be replaced by `fromMaybe`.

Comment: @melpomene added that; it has been a while since I answered Haskell questions and used the language, thanks.

Comment: @4castle thanks for the edit. I don't have a programming environment or editor at the moment at hand (not even a spell checker).

Answer (score 2):

Define an auxilliary function:

```
replaceIfNothing :: Maybe a -> a -> a
replaceIfNothing (Just x) _ = x
replaceIfNothing Nothing  x = x
```

And then you can do:

```
replaceIfNothing shortMonth $
replaceIfNothing longMonth $
replaceIfNothing monthPoint $
-- I think you get the idea now
```

You can also do it as an operator, which I personally think is nicer:

```
(&>) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
(&>) (Just x) _ = x
(&>) Nothing  x = x
infixr 1 &>

shortMonth &> longMonth &> monthPoint &> ...
```

Of course, since this is Haskell, a [quick search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a%20-%3E%20a) shows that this is just [`Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) with the arguments reversed; you can thus just define `replaceIfNothing = flip fromMaybe` (although you have to do `import Data.Maybe` first). It's possible to use `fromMaybe` directly as well, although it feels a little clumsy:

```
flip fromMaybe shortMonth $
flip fromMaybe longMonth $
flip fromMaybe monthPoint $
...
```

Comment: Why not just `shortMonth <|> longMonth <|> monthPoint <|> ...` (using `<|>` from [Control.Applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2))?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, that's even better! I completely forgot about `(<|>)`! I'll edit that in now.

Comment: @melpomene After a bit more thought, it actually turns out that `(<|>)` is not exactly the same as what I've defined: I defined `(&>) :: Maybe a -> a -> a`, whereas `(<|>) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`.

Comment: `<|>` can still be used, you would just unwrap the end result with `fromMaybe` (for the error case)

Comment: @4castle That is definitely one way to go about it. I do think that approach is slightly more boilerplate-ey than necessary though; compare `a &> b &> c` to `fromJust $ a <|> b <|> Just c`.

Comment: It would be `fromMaybe (error ...) $ a <|> b <|> c`.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, you are right actually - for some reason I thought `c` wasn't in `Maybe`.